# Export the list of jars name from Artifactory in excel sheet/text file

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Artifactory 3.3.0 Enterprise edition. My requirement is to get all the jars names from Artifactory(lib-release-local) in excel sheet or text file.

Please can anyone help on this.

Thanks,
Sangeetha

Answer (score 1):

You have an old version of [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/). I suggest you upgrade...
Using [Artifactory 3 API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Artifactory+REST+API) , you can search a repository with a quick `curl` command.

`curl -u <user>:<pass> -XGET "http://<art-host>/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=jar&repos=libs-release-local"`

This will produce a json output of all files matching search string (`name`). You can then parse that and format it to your needs.

I hope this helps.